# field as a permission for other field with CCK

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

i want to have a content type with a phone number field that user can select it be shown to all or not. so i need a field after this field in add content page to give the user this option. but how can i check if user has checked it and then show the phone number in view page??

do i need some php coding for it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a custom template for your content type :
http://drupal.org/node/17565

Or a custom template for your phone cck field :
http://drupal.org/node/62466

In this template you will display phone field depending on the value of the other field, you will need a little bit of php code.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields), and then set the `Make phone number public?` field as the trigger field and `Phone number` filed as the dependent field.

So that only if the first field is set to yes, phone number will be displayed.

Comment: But in that case, the user can't enter his phone number in a way such that it is only visible for him and the administrator. He can only choose between having the field or not.